# FileInputStream error and RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have written a simple code to compare two PDF files, but during the execution I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.io.FileInputStream cannot be cast to org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessRead
    at pdfComparator.PDFComparator.main(PDFComparator.java:29)
```

Can anyone help me understand my mistake? Thanks in advance.

```
package xyz;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import org.apache.pdfbox.cos.COSDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.io.RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class PDFComparator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        if(args.length !=2){
            System.out.println("Usage: java PDFComparator file1 file2");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        String firstFilePath = args[0];
        String secondFilePath = args[1];
        
        File pdfFile1 = new File(firstFilePath);

        File pdfFile2 = new File(secondFilePath);
        
    RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream raFile1 = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(pdfFile1);
    RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream raFile2 = new RandomAccessBufferedFileInputStream(pdfFile2);    
    
        
    PDFParser parser1 = new PDFParser(raFile1);
    parser1.parse();
    COSDocument cosDoc1 = parser1.getDocument();
    PDDocument firstPDF = new PDDocument(cosDoc1);

    PDFParser parser2 = new PDFParser(raFile2);
    parser2.parse();
    COSDocument cosDoc2 = parser2.getDocument();
    PDDocument secondPDF = new PDDocument(cosDoc2);
    

    PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    String text1 = stripper.getText(firstPDF).trim();
    String text2 = stripper.getText(secondPDF).trim();

    if (text1.equals(text2)){
        System.out.println("The two PDF files are identical");
        }else{
        System.out.println("The two PDF files have differences");
        }
    firstPDF.close();
    secondPDF.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Why did you not mark line 29?

Comment: @g00se, yes, you've right, i am currently debugging the code.

Comment: I suspect you posted either the wrong code or the wrong exception

Comment: @TilmanHausherr, indeed there is no FileInputStream, that's why i am confused. My PDFBox version is 2.0.28. The error is shown in the full stack trace.

Comment: Maybe java is confused. Try declaring the two `raFile` variables as the `RandomAccessRead` interface.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. I've just run it without issue

Comment: make sure you have a current jdk. Jdk8 is at 271.

Comment: The issue was related to the filepath in the run configurations. Even with double quotes, there have been problems with spaces in the filepath. Or maybe there is something wrong with the code and it has problems to manage filepaths with spaces.

Comment: *Or maybe there is something wrong with the code and it has problems to manage filepaths with spaces* No, there isn't. I just tested it

Comment: There are easier ways to load a PDF in 2.0, just use `PDDocument.load(File)`

Comment: Giovanni, please take @g00se's comment (*wrong code or wrong exception*) seriously - non-matching code and exception often means that one actually runs different code (e.g. an earlier version of one's code). The exception is about a class cast which isn't in your code at all, so there is a mismatch.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Java 8 is up to Java 8 update 371/372 these days, not 271.